# Accessing dimension of boost multi-arrays in C++

Tags: c++, boost, boost-multi-array

When I run the following with warning flags I get a type conversion warning.

```
#include <boost/multi_array.hpp>

void function (boost::multi_array<unsigned char, 2> matrix) {
  int nrows = matrix.shape()[0];
  int ncols = matrix.shape()[1];
}
```

See warning message below. Does this mean I am implicitly converting a 'long unsigned int' into a regular 'int'?

If so, I think this is what I want (need to perform calculations with nrows, ncols afterwards), and so how would I make the conversion explicit?

```
image.cpp:93:32: warning: conversion to ‘int’ from ‘boost::const_multi_array_ref<float, 2ul, float*>::size_type {aka long unsigned int}’ may alter its value [-Wconversion]
     int nrows = matrix.shape()[0];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Does this mean I am implicitly converting a 'long unsigned int' into a regular 'int'?*

Yes, that is what it means.

If you don't want the warning then don't make `nrows` and `ncols` be of type `int`. The easiest thing to do is to just let the compiler deduce the type i.e.

```
auto nrows = matrix.shape()[0];
auto ncols = matrix.shape()[1];
```

or you can make them of type `size_t`, which is what the standard library uses for the size of containers and won't emit a warning.

Comment: you can use `auto [nrows, ncols] = *reinterpret_cast<std::array<long unsigned, 2>*>(matrix.shape());`... No, I am joking :) ; I don't use Boost.MultiArray, https://godbolt.org/z/ecna5q1Mz